# Android Facebook SDK does not call callback after login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to make a class that handles Facebook logins in my application.
My problem is it doesn't work on all activity.
On that activity it doesn't call the callback.
After the login and authorize application webview is dismissed, the callback doesn't fire.
The last state that printed in Logcat is **OPENING**

Here is my code:

```
public void doLogin() {
              
        
        if ((Session.getActiveSession() == null || !Session.getActiveSession().isOpened())) {
            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("email");

            // start Facebook Login
            openActiveSession(activity, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                // callback when session changes state
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {
                    
                    Log.d("Sessionstate", state.toString());
                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        // make request to the /me API
                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                            Response response) {
                                        if (prgCheckFB.isShowing())
                                            prgCheckFB.dismiss();
                                        if (user != null) {

                                            Log.e("facebookid", id);
                                            doSomething(user);



                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    
                    } 
                }, permissions); 
        }
    }



private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity,
        boolean allowLoginUI, Session.StatusCallback callback,
        List<String> permissions) {
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity)
            .setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback);
    Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();
    if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState())
            || allowLoginUI) {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);
        return session;
    }
    return null;
}
```

`doSomething` is a function that will save the user data in a shared preference.

Is there anything wrong? The function works in some activity but not ALL activities.

Comment: means are you able to get login page or not???

Comment: yes, but the callback not firing after the login page finished

Comment: it mean when you press login button, you are not able to login. Right!!!

Comment: i think i did logged in to FB, because after the login page, i got redirected to the authorization page.

Comment: then what is the problem you are facing???

Comment: I want to do something after the FB is successfully logged in. But, the call back dont get fired at all. So, the doSomething function is never called.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

maybe you forget to handle the results after login...

check the override method **onActivityResult**..

because it handle the results back to the MainActivity,

maybe this can help your problem..

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

**Update 1**

For newer SDK use:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: or use facebook ui helper:
   uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, dialogCallback);

Comment: API has changed slightly, instead of the Session you need to use the CallbackManager:
  callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: I have tried as explained above. but didn't get any callback. It is just coming back to the Page where FB Login Button is placed

Comment: It important to make FB Login Activity as a launcher Activity in the app Manifest

Comment: @konopko what exactly do you mean? I'm having troubles getting my onCompleted method to fire and I don't know why.

Comment: I tried this, it logs in but doesn't return email value and doesn't go inside `FacebookCallback<LoginResult>` does anyone encountered this? how do you solve it?

Comment: worked for me. I've added callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,
resultCode, data); code into onActivityRequest method

Comment: Does OnActivityResult invoked if i'm using it in a Fragment

Answer (score 6):

Having the attribute `android:noHistory="true"` set for your callback activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file will also result with the callback methods not firing.

Comment: Spent hours trying to figure this one out.  I wish I could up-vote 5 times.

Comment: add `android:noHistory="true"` to `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` activity in AndroidManifest.xml saved my day ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced and solve this issue in a strange way. 
First it was working but after i added other social login buttons like Google login, i made its initialize between;

`CallbackManager.Factory.create();`

and

`LoginButton loginButton =(LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook);`

After i moved google initialization to other lines, it has been solved.

So in short words, facebook login initialization must be in a straight way without other code execution.