# Login doesn't work using LoginManager

Tags: android, facebook

The facebook login is showing, I logged into facebook, confirmed the information, but when I go back to my app the AccessToken did not work. When I tested:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext(), new FacebookSdk.InitializeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onInitialized() {
            if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null){
                System.out.println("not logged in yet");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Logged in");
            }
        }
    });
```

the result is **not logged in yet**

This is the code login:

```
public void loginFacebook(View v){

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(UserPerfilActivity.this, "Você Clicou em: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("publish");
            // sharePhotoToFacebook();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.out.println("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            System.out.println("onError");
        }
    });
}
```

But the callbackManager doesn't work, I don't have publish or cancel or error println.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the problem, I added this code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
```

this is the post:
[post stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371842/android-facebook-sdk-does-not-call-callback-after-login)